# adding from_crawler method to scrapy.xlib.pydispatch script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, scrapy

make sure to upvote if you found this question to be well researched and useful to you. Other people deserve the same opportunity to find helpful posts.

I had this functioning code not long ago while using this scrapy spider written in python on windows now it appears this when using scrapy crawl

> ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Importing from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch is deprecated and >will no longer be supported in future Scrapy versions. If you just want to connect >signals use the from_crawler class method, otherwise import pydispatch directly if >needed. See: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762 from >scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

I've viewed their github forum page for an explanation then replaced this package with PyDispatcher 2.0.5 and this returns that the package is not in my conda environment(it is) -- however they've mentioned adding a from_crawler method as a solution to the problem. Im not sure how to do that

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762
in the third comment down they say this

> > @classmethod
> >     def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
> >         spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
> >         crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
> >         return spider

```
import scrapy,time
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

from mysql.connector import (connection)
from scrapy.selector  import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class GetdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'placeholder'
    start_urls = ['placeholder.org/search/sss?postedToday=1']
    cnx = connection.MySQLConnection(user='root', password='',
                                     host='127.0.0.1',
                                     database='placeholder')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            x= Selector(response)
```

as suggested by Luiz and tomjn it seems signals are a solution to running this script alternatively. However, self is used throughout the script and the def spider_closed is used for an action here, i am not sure how to change this to work with the from_crawler method.

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
        sql = "DELETE FROM images WHERE EventDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY"
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        sql = "DELETE FROM dialy_items WHERE EventDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY"
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.cnx.commit()

        self.cursor.close()
        self.cnx.close()
```

Comment: I think the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#signals) have the answer you are looking for. Let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: This seems to be what Luiz is writing in his answer as well, using signals instead of these methods. This should be an answer but i'm not sure how to append it to my script.

Comment: I think you should just replace your `__init__` function with the code given by @Luiz.

Comment: Thats done - do check the post above. really appreciate your reponse, while youre commited to finding a solution, upvote this post?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use built in [Scrapy Signals](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html) to do what you are doing with `pydispatch`. Eg, replace your `__init__` method with `from_crawler`:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super(GetdataSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return spider
```

Do you really have a method called `self.spider_closed` in your spider? If not you really don't need to connect any signal, as Scrapy already connects the `spider_closed` signal to a default `spider_closed` method. In fact, based on the code you shown, the `__init__`, `from_crawler` and `pydispatch` are not needed.

Comment: yes, the script makes use of the self later on, see update

Comment: @EmpireLearning Did you try to use my suggestion? Are you getting errors just changing what I mentioned?

Comment: Yes i used the suggestion in the code, ran the file and nothing happened, no errors but the program didn't execute. It's supposed to open

Comment: also supposed to fill the database with information (that's my test)